# How to call dispatchShell on same shell for another method?

Tags: shell, cakephp

I have a cake shell, say DemoShell. And, from a method 'method1', I want to create another process which executes 'method2' of DemoShell. How can that be done?

```
class DemoShell extends AppShell {
  // some code
  private function method1() {
     // some code
     $success = $this->dispatchShell('Demo', 'method2', $params);
     // some more code
  }

  private function method2() {
      // some code to do something and return boolean value
  }
}
```

I tried this, but method2 isn't getting called.

Comment: You're already in the shell, why don't you simply invoke the method directly?

Comment: I did not want to have a blocking call on method2(). Let it have its own process and finish independently.